# Restore MapState after Job restart/cancellation

Tags: apache-flink

I have to Aggregate the count/sum on event stream for various entities.
event logs(json str) are received from kafka and populate map entityname as key and value is count of the selective attriibutes as json str .

MapState sourceAggregationMap = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(sourceAggregationDesc);

for each event stream repopulate the value .

problem is whenever job gets stopped (failed)/cancelled and when the job gets restarted map state is not getting reinitialized / restored . again count starts from 0.

using Apache flink 1.6.0 
state.backend: rocksdb

Comment: Do you have checkpointing enabled and configured, and are the checkpoints succeeding? You can monitor checkpoints in the webui, or look in the logs to see if they are failing. In the case of a restart, you need to restart with a savepoint as described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/state/savepoints.html#resuming-from-savepoints

Comment: when i run -s it restored state . Thanks for quick reply.
I have enableCheckpointing is 5 sec . 
i am invoking MapState .put for every aggregation count . all i wanted is to restore mapstate when job restarts.
what if job failed before snapshotState method is inovked (5s) ?
Where mapstate.put will perists the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkpoints are used for automatic recovery from failures, and need to be explicitly enabled and configured. Savepoints are triggered manually and are used for restarts and upgrades. Both rely on the same snapshotting mechanism which is described in detail [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/internals/stream_checkpointing.html).

These snapshots capture the entire state of the distributed pipeline, recording offsets into the input queues as well as the state throughout the job graph that has resulted from having ingested the data up to that point. When a failure occurs, the sources are rewound, the state is restored, and processing is resumed.

With the RocksDB state backend, the working state is held on the local disk (in a location you configure), and checkpoints are durably persisted to a distributed file system (again, configurable). When a job is cancelled, the checkpoints are normally deleted (as they will no longer be needed for recovery), but they can be [configured to be retained](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/state/checkpoints.html#retained-checkpoints). If your jobs aren't recovering their state after failures, perhaps the checkpoints are failing, or the job is failing before the first checkpoint can complete. The web ui has a section that displays information about checkpoints, and the logs should also have helpful information.

Update: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61664353/2000823).

Comment: Still one thing what if job fails before we hit checkpoint barrier ? checkpoint 1 minute. i.e job fails at 59th sec . How do we restore the state ?

Comment: If the job fails before the first checkpoint, then there is no state to restore, and you have to start over.

Comment: Ok, assume successful checkpoint at time t  . if job fails at last minute before checkpoint (t+1) . whatever the computation during time t+1 - t is gone  and no way to restore is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. But that's not a problem, provided the source is something like Kafka where the data can be replayed. The lost state will be recomputed.

Comment: Sorry got confused .  when the data gets replayed from the offset time t .data till t+1- t wont be duplicated since we are continuously getting data from kafka.

Comment: Kafka source supports exactly once semantics.hence offset position and operator state gets saved to state back end rocksdb .in case of failure reread data from the last committed offset and recompute aggregation.if we need end to end semantics then sink must support two phase commit using Twophasecommitsinkfunction. Thanks David Anderson