# Flink state empty (reinitialized) after rerun

Tags: scala, state, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to connect two streams, first is persisting in `MapValueState`:
        `RocksDB` save data in checkpoint folder, but after new run, `state` is empty. I run it locally and in flink cluster with cancel submiting in cluster and simply rerun locally

```
 env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend(..)
 env.enableCheckpointing(1000)
 ...

   val productDescriptionStream: KeyedStream[ProductDescription, String] = env.addSource(..)
  .keyBy(_.id)

 val productStockStream: KeyedStream[ProductStock, String] = env.addSource(..)
    .keyBy(_.id)
```

and

```
  productDescriptionStream
  .connect(productStockStream)
  .process(ProductProcessor())
  .setParallelism(1)

env.execute("Product aggregator")
```

ProductProcessor

```
case class ProductProcessor() extends CoProcessFunction[ProductDescription, ProductStock, Product]{
private[this] lazy val stateDescriptor: MapStateDescriptor[String, ProductDescription] =
new MapStateDescriptor[String, ProductDescription](
  "productDescription",
  createTypeInformation[String],
  createTypeInformation[ProductDescription]
)
private[this] lazy val states: MapState[String, ProductDescription] = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(stateDescriptor)

override def processElement1(value: ProductDescription,
ctx: CoProcessFunction[ProductDescription, ProductStock, Product]#Context,out: Collector[Product]
 ): Unit = {
  states.put(value.id, value)
 }}

 override def processElement2(value: ProductStock,
ctx: CoProcessFunction[ProductDescription, ProductStock, Product]#Context, out: Collector[Product]
 ): Unit = {
  if (states.contains(value.id)) {
         val product =Product(
          id = value.id,
          description = Some(states.get(value.id).description),
          stock = Some(value.stock),
          updatedAt = value.updatedAt)
        out.collect(product )
 }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkpoints are created by Flink for recovering from failures, not for resuming after a manual shutdown. When a job is canceled, the default behavior is for Flink to delete the checkpoints. Since the job can no longer fail, it won't need to recover.

You have several options:

(1) Configure your checkpointing to [retain checkpoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/checkpoints.html#retained-checkpoints) when a job is cancelled:

```java
CheckpointConfig config = env.getCheckpointConfig();
config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(
  CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

Then when you restart the job you'll need to indicate that you want it restarted from a specific checkpoint:

```
flink run -s <checkpoint-path> ...
```

Otherwise, whenever you start a job it will begin with an empty state backend.

(2) Instead of canceling the job, use [stop with savepoint](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html#job-management-examples):

```
flink stop [-p targetDirectory] [-d] <jobID>
```

after which you'll again need to use `flink run -s ...` to resume from the savepoint.

Stop with a savepoint is a cleaner approach than relying on there being a recent checkpoint to fall back to.

(3) Or you could use [Ververica Platform Community Edition](https://www.ververica.com/blog/announcing-ververica-platform-community-edition), which raises the level of abstraction to the point where you don't have to manage these details yourself.

Comment: Is there a possible way to point for read checkpoints in for example initialise method implemeting `CheckpointedFunction` and override `initializeState` method, without run app with `flink run -s <checkpoint-path>`

Comment: No. With just `flink run` flink assumes you want to start without loading any state, and even if it wanted to load state wouldn't know where to find it.

Comment: There is, however, an API for reading checkpoints -- see the State Processor API. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html